# Form is Auto Submitting

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts

> **createQuesAdd.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show(){
                var myElement = document.getElementById('hideQ');
                myElement.style.display = '';
                hideQ();
            }
            function hideQ(){
                var myElement = document.getElementById('showQ');
                myElement.style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="showQ" onsubmit="show();">Insert More Question?<input type="submit" value="Yes"/>
            <input type="button" value="No" onclick="window.location.href='Home.jsp';"/>
        </form>
        <form action="saveQuesAdd.do" method="post">
            <table id="hideQ" style="display: none;"> 
                <tr><td><input name="tableName" hidden="true" value="${requestScope.table_name}"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Question No.</td><td><input type="text" name="question_no"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Question:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="" name="question" ></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Option1:</td><td><input type="text" name="option1" /></td></tr> 
                <tr><td>Option2:</td><td><input type="text" name="option2" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Option3:</td><td><input type="text" name="option3" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Option4:</td><td><input type="text" name="option4" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Answer:</td><td><input type="text" name="answer" /></td></tr>   
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create Database"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm coming onto this page which has a totally same form. After at least one entry into the database, the user is forwarded onto this page and is asked whether he wants to make more entries into the database. The problem is when the "Yes" button is clicked, the table shows up (i wanted it to be hidden until the user says) and does not let me do anything and submits itself with the previous entries! and i get an SQL exception saying duplicate copy. Why is it auto submitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        var myElement = document.getElementById('hideQ');
        myElement.style.display = '';
        hideQ();
        return false;
    }
    function hideQ() {
        var myElement = document.getElementById('showQ');
        myElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="showQ" onsubmit="return show()">
    Insert More Question?<input type="submit" value="Yes" />
    <input type="button" value="No" onclick="window.location.href='Home.jsp';" />
</form>
<form action="saveQuesAdd.do" method="post">
    <table id="hideQ" style="display: none;">
        <tr><td><input name="tableName" hidden="true"     value="${requestScope.table_name}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Question No.</td><td><input type="text" name="question_no" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Question:</td><td><textarea rows="3" cols="" name="question">    </textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Option1:</td><td><input type="text" name="option1" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Option2:</td><td><input type="text" name="option2" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Option3:</td><td><input type="text" name="option3" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Option4:</td><td><input type="text" name="option4" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Answer:</td><td><input type="text" name="answer" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create Database" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Update the code as shown above and it will work fine :)

On clicking on the Yes button,you are simply showing the DIV and posting the form so it submit's automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The page is not auto-submitting, you are submitting it when you click the "Yes" button.

Your "Yes" button is a submit.  When you click it, the onsubmit action is being called, which is why you see the form containing the hideQ table.  Since you did not specify an action for the "showQ" form, it defaults to the current document root (to createQuesAdd.jsp).

My recommendation is to change the line:

```
<form id="showQ" onsubmit="show();">Insert More Question?<input type="submit" value="Yes"/>
```

To:

```
<form id="showQ">Insert More Question?<input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="show();"/>
```

You are not actually trying to submit anything with the "Yes" button, so you don't want it to be a submit.

Comment: I tried this but then only the "Yes" button disappears and not the whole statement and "No" button.

Comment: Hmm... my proposed change works on my computer, I can't explain what would go wrong.  With Durai's solution, by calling "return show();" you are returning the False value that show() returns, and thus telling the web browser not to submit the format after all.  The result is the same, so stick with what is working for you.